# wallpaper refresh

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background

I have this simple script, take a look at it please:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/earthwallpaper/
while [  1 ]; do
    COUNTER=0
    while [  $COUNTER -lt 60 ]; do
        wget http://www.opentopia.com/images/cams/world_sunlight_map_rectangular.jpg -O world.jpg
        temp=$(stat -c%s world.jpg)
        if [[ $temp > 1000 ]]
            then    rm world_sunlight_Wallpaper.jpg
                    mv world.jpg world_sunlight_Wallpaper.jpg
                break
        fi
        sleep 5
            let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
    done
    pcmanfm --set-wallpaper=~/earthwallpaper/world_sunlight_Wallpaper.jpg
    sleep 60m
done
```

It is downloading picture from web every hour, save file to disk and set up as desktop wallpaper. One file, same name. Downloading and saving works fine, but refreshing wallpaper on desktop works only once - only first time. Next hour it won't change. The picture is saved in some cache and the system won't change it even the file is updated, on the desktop I see only the picture downloaded first time. After system restart, the picture will change.

So is it possible to refresh wallpaper on desktop which has the same name?

Comment: Have you thought about adding your script to a cronjob instead of having the `while [ 1 ]` loop in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution for this problem is addinng this in script:

pcmanfm --wallpaper-mode=center

pcmanfm --wallpaper-mode=stretch

thanx to toxicbreakfast (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154734)

:)